# Cast generic T to Object[]

Tags: java, generics

Is it possible to cast a generic into a Object[] if not what is the way?

```
 public class OneClass<T extends Serializable> {

    public void someMethod()
    {
        T castObject = (T) value;
        //The method createArrayOf(String, Object[]) in the type Connection is not applicable for the arguments (String, T)
        //So method signature is createArrayOf(String, Object[])
        Array array = connection.createArrayOf("integer", castObject);
    }

  }
```

But I would want to use this generic as next:

```
OneClass<Integer[]>
```

or

```
OneClass<String[][]>
```

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood the syntax of casting. If you want to cast to `Object[]`, cast with `(Object[])`, not with `(T)`.

Comment: With your update; I still think that my answer solves that "casting" problem. Your code still looks weird; as at least java.lang.Array only has **static** methods; so there is absolutely no point in instantiating it. But maybe that is some other Array class ...

Comment: @GhostCat, it's `java.sql.Array`.

Comment: Note that the cast doesn't do any kind of conversion:  this will only work if the generic value actually *is* an `Object[]`.  And if it's required to be an `Object[]`, there's not much point in having it be generic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, it is possible; say:

```
T whatever = ... coming from somewhere

Object[] castedObjects = (Object[]) whatever;
```

If its a good idea; that might be a whole lot different discussion. But in order to have that discussion, we would have to see more "context" - what are your requirements; what is the intention of that class; what is it supposed to do with those arrays of object?!

But your immediate problem can easily be fixed; as shown above.